If function $f$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition, then $f(A)$ has measure zero if $A$ does. Trying to understand my textbook's solution.
I am trying to understand a solution to this Exercise given by my textbook :

Suppose $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^k$ is a function from an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ satisfying the Lipschitz condition, meaning there
exists a constant $L > 0$ such that $$||f(x) - f(y)|| \leq L ||x -
y||, \quad x, y \in U.$$ Suppose $A$ is a subset of $U$ with measure
zero.
Prove that $f(A)$ has measure zero.

Here is the solution given in my textbook:

For $n \in \mathbb N$ let $A_n := B_n(0) \cap A$. Then $A_n$ has measure zero as $A_n \subseteq A$ for each $n$ and we have $A = \bigcup_n A_n$.
It is easy to see that $f(A_n)$ is of measure zero for each $n$. But as
\[
f(A) = f\left(\bigcup_n A_n\right) = \bigcup_n f(A_n)
\]
$f(A)$ is a countable union of sets of measure zero and has therefore measure zero.

I don't see why $f(A_n)$ is of measure zero for each $n$ (may be according to Lipschitz condition?)
Could someone explain this for me? Thanks in advance!

What is $B_n(0)$ ? Which textbook is this Exercise from ?

Is it Lebesgue measure? And how did the textbook define the measure?

We say that a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$
n has measure zero (or is negligible) if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists countably
many rectangles $Q_1, Q_2, . . .$ so that $A \subset \cup Q_k$ and $\sum
Vol(Q_k) < \epsilon$.

$B_n(0)$ is the ball with center $O$, radius $n$
